# How to delete a page if sub report is blank?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an ASP.NET application written in C# with the Crystal report. Each page of this report has a header, which always has data, and also a sub report Notes that can be blank. I don't want to show pages that have blank sub report, I need to remove them completely. Without a header this would be pretty simple, but I cannot figure out how to do this in my case.

I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on your sub report and click on Format Oject.Now you can see the following window

[image]

Then check the Supress Blank Subreport checkbox and click OK button.I think this method will work for you

Comment: Thank you. This would suppress only subreport, or section, it won't delete the whole page. My problem is the header which always has some data.

Comment: If the subreport is the only object in the section, then you can go into Section Expert and check "Suppress Blank Section".

Comment: Thank you. No, there are other objects, including subreports.